# Need to remove Offset from time zone string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the timezone from a timestamp with z. 
For example

```
2019-08-14T21:21-0100
```

needs to be replaced with `2019-08-14T21:21Z`. The regex I am using right now is `.replace(/\+[^/+]+$/,"Z")`
but it only works with negative offset like -0100 but doesn't work with +0100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as

```js
let zone = "2019-08-14T21:21-0100";

zone = zone.replace(/[-+]\d+$/, "Z");
console.log(zone);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `[+-]\d{4}$` to select it and replace it with something else.

```js
const result = '2019-08-14T21:21-0100'.replace(/[+-]\d{4}$/, 'Z');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
console.log(
  [
      '2021-12-31T23:59:59+02:00',
      '2021-12-31T21:59:59+0200', // mind no semicolon
      '2021-12-31T20:59:59-02:00',
      '2021-12-31T19:59:59-0200',
      '2021-12-31T18:59:59-02',
      '2021-12-31T17:59:59+02',
      '2021-12-31T16:59:59Z',
      '2021-12-31',
  ].map(
      i => i.replace(
          /(T.*)(Z|[+-](\d{2}:?\d{2}$)|([+-]\d{2}$))/, 
          '$1ZULU' // here mind the match $1
      )
  )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).